# Laravel Update only 1 row?

Tags: laravel-5

Is there a way to update only 1 row in Laravel 5? I want to set the value of selected to true from only 1 row, ordered by id:

Ill tried:

```
DB::table('user_tabs')->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->update(array('selected' => true));
```

And:

```
DB::table('user_tabs')->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->update(array('selected' => true));
```

but it is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DB::table('user_tabs')->where('user_id', $user_id)->update(['selected' => true]);
```

You were trying to update the record after selecting it, which confused the Query Builder.

Also, have a look at [Eloquent models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent). They make database interactions a little nicer.